# How to insert unicode symbol in EditText from Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I've a custom keyboard from where I want to insert the symbol ⏺ in the currently active EditText. I use this:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("\u23FA", "\u23FA".length());
```

But this inserts just a space (no visible character). I think Android doesn't support all unicode characters but is there any way to insert this symbol??

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try the following 2 options in your java code:

```
editText.setText("\u23FA");
```

or

```
editText.getText().append("\u23FA");
```

let me know how you got on ok?

Comment: But how can I access editText of currently active app from my custom keyboard?

Comment: can you send me the code that you have written as i am not sure of what your question is? try to ellaborate a bit more please @Jeet

Comment: Sure. I'm developing a custom keyboard. It can be shown up in any app. Now suppose this keyboard is brought up in Messages app. There is a button in the keyboard which when tapped, should insert ⏺ in the EditText of Messages app.     But I'm unable to insert this symbol. Just a space is inserted everytime. If I change the code to some other unicode character (like: ©), it shows up properly.

Comment: @jeet  can you copy and paste the fraction of the code in question so I can try to make it work for you?